# Why have I been banned for those 2 down votes questions?

Tags: discussion, support

When I asked [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/92792/57727) question, I tried my best to make it clear and also I tried to put two different links, but no matter what, it appeared the same links as if they get cloned. And so, I left it as it, and I described only what I saw from these 2 videos. I don’t see where I did mistake that I have got down votes for this, to me it seemed that it is 100% clarified.

Can you please show me the mistakes from this post?

And in [second](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/93013/57727) post, I have asked a question just to codify it because I didn’t quit understood the ending of its movie. And now, someone has edited in a proper manner 100%, why do I still got down votes?

Can you please show me how to write excellent questions? I mean those 2 question to be written in excellent manner.

Answer (score 9):

You didn't. If you read the question ban message you got, it clearly states that deleted questions count towards the ban and you have five - four of which have negative scores (-3 or -5).

Generally, we encourage you to improve your questions rather than deleting them but these questions are completely off topic here. You have:

- [One identification question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84825/can-anyone-identify-this-movie).
- Two [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81048/does-anybody-knows-exactly-when-will-come-a-sequel-for-district-9) asking for [speculation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83376/what-we-ll-see-in-independence-day-intergalactic-journey-and-when-it-is-the-rele) about future releases of films.
- One question asking for help [contacting a production company](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81271/where-can-i-share-my-ideas-for-independence-day-intergalactic-journey).

All of these are noted as being off topic on the [help page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that defines the scope of this site:

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> - Identifying a movie or TV series
> - Locating or purchasing movie or TV content
> - Technology questions about playing content
> - Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.
> - TV news, sports and current affairs
> - A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.
> - Opinions about or recommendations for a movie or TV show

OK, well, the asking for help contacting a production company isn't listed but it's well beyond our scope. This isn't information we specialize in or can provide for you.

We hope that you read this information as we link to it whenever questions get closed. We can't remove them from your account, you'll have to improve your existing questions or the future ones you ask here.

At this point, you have only been question banned for a week, so you'll be able to ask another question then but I strongly recommend that you edit any questions that have been closed or downvoted in an effort to have them reopened and (hopefully) upvoted as you will likely get re-banned if you don't improve your question score.

The fifth deleted question is [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92996/what-kind-of-electricity-is-the-black-hole-showing) - it was closed for being unclear but has zero score. If you can reword it to be clearer, it may get upvoted and answered.

As to your YouTube links, you included two links in the original question and then changed them both in an edit. I don't know which is which but that's why your links were always the same. I've fixed your links for you - please check if they're what you want them to be. I've also fixed the question.

I recommend that you avoid guessing at the answer in your questions in the future. These parts of your questions seem to cause confusion in a couple of cases and whether you're correct or not, the answers will explain what the answer is, so there's no reason to guess what the answer is in the question.

Comment: Ok. But what if those down votes questions which I posted are off topic, what should I do with them? Should I delete them? Because I do not want to waste other’s efforts.

Comment: I don’t know how much to codify them.